# Why didn't my MiKTeX download include MiKTeX Settings (Admin)?

Tags: miktex2.9

I'm trying to get Latex up and running on my new Windows 10 laptop. I started by downloading MiKTeX2.9 (basic) from https://miktex.org/download, which is where most websites pointed me. I then discovered that many pretty basic packages such as amsthm and graphicx don't show up on the MiKTeX console and have to be installed manually. Since I don't really have experience doing this, I searched online for a guide and the best I found was this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYJkU17Wfnc. The instructions on the video are super clear and make sense (I wish more guides were like this) but I get stuck at the step where the guy opens MiKTeX Settings (Admin) because for some reason it can't be found on my laptop. It seems that the only app/program that got downloaded with MiKTeX is MiKTeX Console, and every Google search of "MiKTeX Settings (Admin)" turns up an offhand reference to it as part of the "MiKTeX group" with the implication that everyone automatically has all of these apps if they downloaded MiKTeX. There is no place to download MiKTeX Settings (Admin) on its own.

Can anyone explain why everyone else doing MiKTeX seems to have a different group of MiKTeX apps than I have? It honestly feels ridiculous that I'm stuck at this step, and I really don't want to start all over again with installing Latex via a completely different route.

(By the way, I tried seeing if the step of the instructions involving MiKTeX Settings (Admin) could be accomplished by going to Settings on MiKTeX Console, where I could certainly add the route to where I'm keeping the packages, but I can't find a button that actually gets the packages installed...)

Comment: your video is outdated. Today everything is done in the miktex console.

Comment: but you shouldn't have to install graphicx, that is always included.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Ulrike. Can I ask then (1) how are further packages installed through the miktex console? and (2) if graphicx is always included then why does my tex file stop compiling at the line "\includegraphics{{pic/}}"?

Comment: (1) open the console and look around. It is rather obvious where the packages are.  Check also https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console. (2) because your syntax is wrong.

Comment: Above I mistyped: my command is \includegraphics{{pics/}}. It works fine with tex on my old laptop (I'm trying to compile a tex document that compiled fine on the old laptop).

Comment: (1) Yes it's obvious where the packages are, but the list of packages for some reason doesn't include basic things like amsthm.  And meanwhile the editor can't read the command "\newtheorem" when I try to compile.

Comment: the packages are collections. amsthm is in `amscls`.  And I can't believe that you have a graphic whose name ends with /. `{{pics/}}` looks like an argument for `\graphicspath` not for `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Sorry, sorry. You're right: for some reason I keep miswriting the command. It's \graphicspath{{pics/}}. So the mystery now is why the compiler keeps getting stuck on commands like \graphicspath{{pics/}} and \newtheorem...

Comment: It would help a lot if you wouldn't mention only snippets (even more if they are wrong). Show a small complete example that errors, and  show the complete log-file.